# Query on countability of sets and its subset 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

> Consider the following statements.
>
> 1.If every subset of a set is countable then set is countable.
>
> 2.If every **proper** subset of a set is countable then set is countable.

Then-

($a$)1  correct 2 may or may not correct.

($b$)2  correct 1 may or may not correct.

($c$)Both may or may not correct.

($d$)Both correct.

I attemped it using contrapositive of both the statements which are as-

(1) if a set is uncountable then there is atleast one subset which is uncountable.

(2) if a set is uncountable then there is atleast one proper subset which is uncountable.

**My Argument**:Both the contrapositive statements are satisfied by $\mathbb R$ which is uncountable but it has $\mathbb Z$ as  subset which is countable.

From this it seems that (C) is true

But my argument  seems not strong as "for example is not a proof".

Please clarify my doubt..

Answer (score 0):

For part a, notice that every set is a subset of itself. For part b notice that removing even a single element gives a proper subset which is countable, so the original set is countable too.

Your example of $\mathbb R$ is not correct. The reason is that to falsify a "there exists atleast one" type of statement, it is not enough to give a counter-example. You have to show that such an example is impossible to construct.

Comment: :it means d is correct!!?

Comment: @PKStyles You tell me.